# What is the image of a strip in $\mathbb{R}^2$ under a $2 \times 2$ hyperbolic matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix with $\mathrm{det}(A)=1$, two eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\,\lambda_2$ with $\lambda_1<1<\lambda_2$ and the corresponding eigenvectors to $\lambda_1,\, \lambda_2$ being the horizontal and vertical axis respectively. If $L \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is a line with positive slope, a unit-neighbourhood of $L$ is mapped under $A$ to $C$-neighbourhood of the line $A(L)$ where $C>0$ is a not-yet-known constant.

In a proof I am reading about the properties of a map related to $A$, they give a bound on $C$ that I cannot derive myself. If $\alpha$ is the angle of $L$ to the horizontal and $\beta$ the angle of $A(L)$ to the horizontal, it is stated that
\begin{equation*}
C \leq \lambda_1 \frac{\sin(\beta)}{\sin(\alpha)}.
\end{equation*}

My approach was to consider a unit normal vector to $L$, find its image under $A$ and to project this down onto a unit normal of $A(L)$. While I believe this gives a correct value for $C$, it is harder to deduce information from this larger expression (and so it is not as desirable for the proof) than the bound above. How can we show the above bound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L:y=mx+b$ with $\tan\alpha=m$. We can work out the unit neighbourhood of $L$ as $y=mx+b\pm\sec\alpha$.*

From the given conditions
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}\lambda_1&0\\0&\lambda_1^{-1}\end{bmatrix}$$
and so $A$ maps $(x,y)$ to $(x',y')=(\lambda_1x,\lambda_1^{-1}y)$.
$$\lambda_1y'=m\lambda_1^{-1}x'+b\pm\sec\alpha$$
$$y'=m\lambda_1^{-2}x'+b\lambda_1^{-1}\pm\lambda_1^{-1}\sec\alpha$$
which gives
$$\tan\beta=m\lambda_1^{-2}$$
$$C=\lambda_1^{-1}\frac{\cos\beta}{\cos\alpha}^*$$
Take the quotient of the two tangents:
$$\frac{\tan\beta}{\tan\alpha}=\lambda_1^{-2}=\frac{\sin\beta}{\sin\alpha}\frac{\cos\alpha}{\cos\beta}$$
$$\lambda_1^{-2}=\frac{\sin\beta}{\sin\alpha}\frac1{C\lambda_1}$$
$$C=\lambda_1\frac{\sin\beta}{\sin\alpha}$$
as desired.

*For pictorial derivations, see the below images:
[image]
[image]